# Direction of angular momentum and torque being applied

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

does the direction of external torque and angular momentum resulting from the external torque  same? if not, then why it is so and in what cases?

Comment: What have you found in your own research? You can find this information in any deent physics text.

Comment: Answering the question that *are the directions of acceleration and the velocity resulting due to it the same?*, will lead you to this question's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector sum of the external torques determines the rate of change of the angular momentum vector.  For an object on an axle, the vector representing the torque (relative to the axle) is defined as being along the axle.  Starting from zero, the vector representing the increase in the angular momentum would be in that same direction along the axle.
For an object already spinning, a torque vector at right angle to the axis would cause the angular momentum vector to swing in the direction of the torque vector (assuming the axis is free to move).  (You may want to look up the associated right hand rules.)